# Self-inverse matrices with integers with pairwise different absolut values.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

Let A be a self-inverse matrix ($A=A^{-1}$) with integer values such that no
 two integers have the same absolut value. Let M be the maximum of the absolut
 values (maximum-norm) of A. Which M is the least possible for a given size
 of A ?

There are no 2x2 - matrices with the desired property.

For 3x3-matrices , my current record is

[[ 13 , 8 , -16 ][-9 , -5 , 12 ][ 6 , 4 , -7 ]]

with M = 16

For 4x4-matrices , my current record is

[[  29,-26, -24 , 18 ][ 15 , -14 , -12 , 9] [-6 , 7 , 5 , -3] [-33 , 31 , 28 , -20 ]]

with M = 33

Comment: [-15, -7, -21, 2, 0, 3, 10, 5, 14]  21 is my current record for 3x3-matrices containing a 0.

Comment: [0, -2, 1, 3, 13, 27, -23, -24, 9, 18, -16, -15, 6, 12, -10, -11]  27 is my current record for 4x4-matrices conatining a 0.

Comment: [5, -4, -2, 6; -16, 15, 9, -23; -13, 14, 7, -20; -19, 18, 10, -27]   27  is my new record for 4x4-matrices without a 0.

Comment: [39, -36, 8, -28, 18; 68, -63, 14, -50, 32; 58, -52, 11, -42, 26; 22, -20, 4, -15, 10; 60, -56, 12, -44, 29]   68  is my record for 5x5-matrices.